# calculate price in date range in mysql,java

Tags: java, mysql

We have table and its data look like

```
startDate|endDate |price
=========+========+========  
1 dec    | 15 dec | 100  
16 dec   |31 dec  | 200  
1 jan    | 31 Jan | 300  
1 feb    | 10 feb | 30
15 feb   | 28 feb | 40
1 march  | 15 march | 50
```

The price is one day price. Now i want to calculate price between date say 1dec to 10 dec. then price will be (100 * 10 days). another condition is calculate price between 1 dec to 15 jan then price will be((100 * 15 days)+(200*15days)+(300*15days)). and one more condition is calculate price between 20feb to 5 march then price will be (40*8days + 50*5). How to calculate based on the data price.

Comment: Why not you calculate on the calculator?

Comment: You need to get the date from the database, then get the datediff and multiply the datediff (days) with the price.

Comment: +1 for the interesting question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to select any interval fitting query dates. Then you can calculate number of days for each interval and price for interval. Then just sum it.

```
select 
 SUM(
  DATEDIFF(
   if( end_date > '2012-09-12', '2012-09-12', end_date ),
   if( start_date < '2012-09-02', '2012-09-02', start_date )
  ) * price
 )
from prices where start_date < '2012-09-12' and end_date > '2012-09-02'
```

SqlFiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abc0b/11/0

This is example for time in INT

```
select 
 SUM(
  DATEDIFF(
   if( end_date > '2012-09-12', '2012-09-12', end_date ),
   if( start_date < '2012-09-02', '2012-09-02', start_date )
  ) * price
 )
from (
 select 
  FROM_UNIXTIME( start_date, '%Y-%m-%d' ) as start_date,
  FROM_UNIXTIME( end_date, '%Y-%m-%d' ) as end_date,
  price
 from prices where start_date <  UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '2012-09-12' ) and end_date >  UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '2012-09-02' )
) as l
```

Edit : fixed example, thanks for fiddle
Edit 2 : Unix timestamp example

Comment: in table startDate and endDate are stored as bigint values. ow if run the your query i get following error

Comment: Error Code: 1579
Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'

Comment: SELECT 
 SUM(
  DATEDIFF(
   IF( end_date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-11-15')*1000, UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-11-15')*1000, end_date ),
   IF( start_date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-11-01')*1000, UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-11-01')*1000, start_date )
  ) * price
 ) AS T
FROM city_daypart_price_range WHERE start_date < 1354300200352 AND end_date > 1355509800352

Comment: Try to copy my example and then use it (Second one)

Comment: and can you send me fiddle with timestamp dates ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try the following:

Query:

```
select price*10
  from prices
  where '2012-09-02' between start_date
  and start_date + interval 10 day
```

Results:

```
PRICE*10
1010
```

Reference: * [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abc0b/32)

Currenlty the interval is merely a static value. You may pass this as a dynamic value to your query. In order to get multiple day ranges involved, all you need is to pass different intervals between different start dates to catch the price. Let me know if it's clear or if you require further clarification :)

Comment: and what will happen if the first interval will 5 days, second 10 and third 15 ?

Comment: @SergeS can you show me where the error is? It works fine in the attached SQLFIDDLE. :) Anyway I realize the OP's request far advanced than the first impression I got. I noticed the erro in the price. It should be 1010. Fixed.

Comment: that was the issue ... and it mess my head, so i "seen" error in between

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**: I've kept my answer but no longer agree with it, see the comments for why.

One possible answer, though I don't think it's the best (see other answers) is to denormalize your data:

```
day    | price
=======+======
1 dec  | 100
2 dec  | 100
3 dec  | 100
4 dec  | 100
...
15 dec | 100
16 dec | 200
17 dec | 200
...
```

Then your answer is as simple as:

```
select sum(price) from mytable where day > '1 dec' and day < '15 jan'
```

This may make your data easier to work with and more intuitive, but with some drawbacks:

- It may be slower; querying over many rows is slower than 1 row if the range stays the same for a long time
- It may be slower to update (for the same reason).

Comment: Denormalization is a bit of hell

Comment: @SergeS is there a good article you could link me to explaining why?  It sounds like you (and the upvotes that agree) have a strong opinion on it.

Comment: + overlaps can be sloved by removing endDate (and calculating it always) - it will make selects more difficult but it slove this issue. Queries to figure out cost are fast - why do you think so ? Query over 90 rows is faster than query over 6 rows ? Updates to a price for a range are easier - same as before - update over 15 rows is faster than update for 1 row ?

Comment: A part of answer is in my reply to your "benefits" ... but basically any time you need to select / update more data, it is slower ... normalization will decrease amout of data